# Printing all anagrams of a given string from a text file

Tags: python, anagram

I'm writing a program which takes the input string and prints out all anagrams of the string, from a text file, in a list.

So far, I've got the following; but nothing is returned and I don't quite understand why.

```
def anagrams( s1, s2 ):
    s1_list = list(s1.lower())
    s1_list.sort()
    s2_list = list(s2.lower())
    s2_list.sort()

    if s1.lower() == s2.lower():
        return(False)
    elif s1_list == s2_list:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False) 

def find_all_anagrams( string ):

    anagrams_list = []

    with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject:

        line = fileObject.readline()

        if anagrams(string, line):
            anagrams_list.append(line)
    return anagrams_list
```

Comment: How are you calling your `find_all_anagrams` function?

Comment: @slider as such `print(find_all_anagrams('python'))`

Comment: `find_all_anagrams` isn't returning anything right now. Try adding `return anagrams_list` at the end

Comment: @boonwj aah yes. forgot to add that, but upon adding that nothing seems to be in the list and I can't quite figure out why. The list is empty with no found anagrams

Comment: So now that's a different problem :P Your code seems to only be reading the first line in `english_words.txt`. Are you only comparing your input string with 1 word in the file?

Comment: @boonwj ohright. no the code should be comparing the string to all words in the text file. how would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the words (I'm assuming one per line) in `english_words.txt`. You also need strip any newline characters from each word before you call `anagrams()`.

```
def find_all_anagrams( string ):
    anagrams_list = []
    with open("english_words.txt", "r") as fileObject:
        for line in fileObject: # check all lines
            word = line.strip() # strip newline characters
            if anagrams(string, word):
                anagrams_list.append(word)
    return anagrams_list # finally return results
```